# PyQt / PySide Echo signals of another object without subclassing

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals, pyside

I'm managing some long running tasks using signals and slots to track progress and such.  I had a Run class that starts like this:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Run(QtCore.QObject):
    running = QtCore.Signal(bool)
    finished = QtCore.Signal(object)
    status = QtCore.Signal(str)
    message = QtCore.Signal(object)
    progress = QtCore.Signal(float)
    time_remaining_update = QtCore.Signal(str)
    initialized = QtCore.Signal()
    failed = QtCore.Signal(object)
    pitch_update = QtCore.Signal(float)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        #... rest of the class ...
```

I recently refactored some things and wrote a Task class which includes a Run instance as an attribute.  I would like to "echo" many of the Run's signals upstream.  This is my current solution:

```
class Task(QtCore.QObject):

    #Signals echoed from Run
    running = QtCore.Signal(bool)
    status = QtCore.Signal(str)
    message = QtCore.Signal(object)
    progress = QtCore.Signal(float)
    time_remaining_update = QtCore.Signal(str)
    initialized = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, run, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.run = run

        #Echo signals from run
        signals = ['running', 'status', 'message', 'progress', 'time_remaining_update', 'initialized']
        for signal in signals:
            #Re-emit the signal
            getattr(self.run, signal).connect(lambda *args: getattr(self, signal).emit(*args))

        #... rest of class ...
```

I confirmed that the `lambda *args: func(*args)` pattern will avoid passing anything to func if nothing is passed to the lambda, which is necessary to obey the different signals' signatures.

Is this the best way to handle "echoing" or "bouncing" signals from one QObject to another?  I'm basically trying to preserve some of the Run API while changing/adding other aspects with my Task API.

I realize that I can get all of the Run API by subclassing and overriding things I want to change, but I didn't want to subclass since Task handles restarting the run after failure.  I'd like to keep the run logic separate from the code that handles restarting the run.  There are also Run signals and methods that I don't want propagated by Task.

The only more elegant solution I can think of is to automate the creation of the Task signals... maybe make a echo_signals decorator that takes a QObject and a list of signal names that then does these things?

Is there a Qt feature for implementing this more elegantly?  Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the purpose of all this indirection? Why can't consumers of the Task class just do, e.g. `task.run.status.connect(handler)`? (PS: there's a bug in your current code, because `signal` inside the `lambda` isn't scoped properly. You need to do `lambda *args, signal=signal: ...`).

Comment: Thanks - yeah the scoping problem gave me errors I didn't understand, so I abandoned this idea.  My current solution is to do as you say and reference task.run.  I guess it's easy to try to be clever and just create more problems.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt you can connect signals to other signals, unless I'm missing something regarding your example.